# Is it possible to get the valid hex address of CHAR in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the valid memory address of CHAR **A4** and **b5** but when I try to reach that address using **Hex Editor** it's not reading the address that I have already got in my console output after compiling.
**Hex Editor** is validating the address as invalid address.

My Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main ()
{
{   //INT
    cout << "INT" << '\n';
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "int a " << "= " << a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "int a " << "= " << a << " " << "at " << "address " << &a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "int b " << "= " << b << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "int b " << "= " << b << " " << "at " << "address " << &b << '\n';
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << '\n';
}
{
    //SHORT
    cout << "SHORT" << '\n';
    short a = 2, b = 3;
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "short a " << "= " << a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "short a " << "= " << a << " " << "at " << "address " << &a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "short b " << "= " << b << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "short b " << "= " << b << " " << "at " << "address " << &b << '\n';
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << '\n';
}
{
    //FLOAT
    cout << "FLOAT" << '\n';
    float a = 2, b = 3.1;
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "float a " << "= " << a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "float a " << "= " << a << " " << "at " << "address " << &a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "float b " << "= " << b << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "float b " << "= " << b << " " << "at " << "address " << &b << '\n';
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << '\n';
}
{
//DOUBLE
    cout << "DOUBLE" << '\n';
    double a = 20, b = 30.1;
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "double a " << "= " << a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "double a " << "= " << a << " " << "at " << "address " << &a << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "double b " << "= " << b << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "double b " << "= " << b << " " << "at " << "address " << &b << '\n';
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << '\n';
}
{
//CHAR
    cout << "CHAR" << '\n';
    char A4 = 'A' , b5 = 'B' ;
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "Char A4 " << "= " << A4 << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "Char A4 " << "= " << A4 << " " << "at " << "address " << &A4 << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "Char b5 " << "= " << b5 << '\n';
    cout << "Result: " << "for " << "Char b5 " << "= " << b5 << " " << "at " << "address " << &b5 << '\n';
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << '\n';
}
}
```

Comment: An address is an address (a number is a number), regardless of whether you print it in decimal, hex, binary or some other base. It's the *same* address/number.

Comment: Can you post the output that doesn't make sense to you, and *what specifically* is wrong with it?  I don't see any `char** a4` in your program.

Comment: You can always use `std::hex` with `std::cout`. I forget if it works with pointers, but it will work with ` uintptr_t`, which is an integral value representing the address of a pointer.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/

Comment: @NicholasM I am getting address = AÜÖÖÖÖ>@ for A4 and 
address = BAÜÖÖÖÖ>@ for b5
Hex Editor is not accepting these values as hex addresses.

Comment: I assume you are trying to read your program's memory using some hex editor? Is your program still running? Addresses become invalid when your program ends and the memory pages are released back to the OS

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes I am using Hex Editor Neo latest version and it fails to read the address AÜÖÖÖÖ>@ and BAÜÖÖÖÖ>@

Comment: Even more, the values are only meaningful to the process. These are virtual addresses, not physical ones! Note: I'm assuming you are running a common OS, not on bare silicon.

Comment: As a note, some variables will live only in registers, which have no address.  When you take the address of a variable, it can't reside in a register any more and must reside in memory.  Local and temporary memory may be reused during the execution of a program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the list of overloads for `operator<<` for streams. The one for `char const*` assumes a zero-terminated string at that address. What you want is the overload for `void const*`. For other types of pointees, that conversion is done implicitly by the compiler, for `char` you need to make it explicitly yourself:

```
cout << static_cast<void const*>(&b5) << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you to Solve and I have the valid address now for b5 = 0x61fee6

Answer (score 3):

```
char A4 = 'A';
cout << &A4;
```

Is printing `char*`, when you print a `char*` the standard library tries to print a null terminated character string. As you only have a single character there is no null terminator so junk gets printed until the standard library happens to find a null byte, this is undefined behaviour.

To print a pointer rather than a string you need to cast to a different pointer type, for example:

```
char A4 = 'A';
cout << static_cast<void*>(&A4);
```

Comment: Great explanation.